# Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource

Tags: java, mongodb, database-connection, jhipster, database

I have no Idea why this error occurs, I did not do anything, created a new vagrant machine with latest version of jhipster created new microservice and started the application, i get the below mentioned error, any help?

```
    2017-07-20 07:36:58,144 ERROR restartedMain o.s.b.SpringApplication:771 - Application startup failed
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [com/nearbuy/ngservice/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
        at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
        at com.nearbuy.ngservice.NgServiceApp.main(NgServiceApp.java:68)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
        at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:168)
        at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:141)
        at com.github.mongobee.utils.ChangeService.fetchChangeLogs(ChangeService.java:43)
        at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.executeMigration(Mongobee.java:166)
        at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.execute(Mongobee.java:153)
        at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.afterPropertiesSet(Mongobee.java:123)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
        ... 19 common frames omitted
```

Comment: It's very likely a problem of classpath with a version of guava that is not compatible with the one mongobee requires. Have you checked your deps with ` mvnw dependency:tree` ?

Comment: What do you want me to check in this?

Comment: Maven will tell you which version of guava was omitted for duplicate and then you can either force a version as @tommynicoletti proposed or exclude a transitive dependency.

Comment: (*) - dependencies omitted (listed previously) and guava version shows as com.google.guava:guava:16.0 -> 18.0

Comment: OK, then search whether guava project has mentioned API changes in their changelog https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/ReleaseHistory and look at the deps that require guava to see whether they have updated guava, or an open issue about this. Usual dep checking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I changed com.google.guava dependency from version 18 to version 22 (downloaded from [latest guava relase](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/Release22)) and ERORR as you mentioned go away.

[image]

Comment: OK, yes this is the solution, but I am having hard time changing the version of guava, looks like iterator method only exists in guava version 22.0

Comment: Guava version 18.0 has no method iterator, hence the error method not found, there is a problem with Dependencies in jhipster, I do not know how to create a bug there so I hope they come to know with this SO post, I think the latest version of jhipster is broken if I put guava 18.0 I get some other exception in microservice gateway, anyway thanks for the help, going back to last working version:(

Comment: Glad to help you. I met the same issue one hour after you, because I updated my JHipster Generator version to v4.6.2. I hope they will fix soon.

Comment: "They" will fix it if you report the problem on github and better if you submit a pull request to fix it.

Comment: I submitted a pull request yet, I had the same error.
https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/pull/6298