# Uaa Jhipster 4.5.2

Tags: jhipster

I created an UAA from Jhipster:

```
? (1/16) Which *type* of application would you like to create? [BETA] JHipster UAA server (for microservice OAuth2 authentication)
? (2/16) What is the base name of your application? uaa
? (3/16) As you are running in a microservice architecture, on which port would like your server to run? It should be unique to avoid port conflicts. 9999
? (4/16) What is your default Java package name? com.xxx.uaa
? (5/16) Do you want to use the JHipster Registry to configure, monitor and scale your microservices and gateways? Yes
? (6/16) Which *type* of database would you like to use? MongoDB
? (7/16) Would you like to use Maven or Gradle for building the backend? Gradle
? (8/16) Which other technologies would you like to use? 
? (9/16) Would you like to enable internationalization support? Yes
? Please choose the native language of the application Spanish
? Please choose additional languages to install English
? (10/16) Besides JUnit and Karma, which testing frameworks would you like to use?  
? (11/16) Would you like to install other generators from the JHipster Marketplace? No
```

And once I've created it execute:

```
./gradlew
```

And give me the following error

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource [com/abalia/uaa/config/DatabaseConfiguration.class]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1628)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:483)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:761)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:867)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:543)
    at org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.refresh(EmbeddedWebApplicationContext.java:122)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:693)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:360)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:303)
    at com.abalia.uaa.UaaApp.main(UaaApp.java:69)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.google.common.collect.Sets$SetView.iterator()Lcom/google/common/collect/UnmodifiableIterator;
    at org.reflections.Reflections.expandSuperTypes(Reflections.java:380)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:126)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:168)
    at org.reflections.Reflections.<init>(Reflections.java:141)
    at com.github.mongobee.utils.ChangeService.fetchChangeLogs(ChangeService.java:43)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.executeMigration(Mongobee.java:166)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.execute(Mongobee.java:153)
    at com.github.mongobee.Mongobee.afterPropertiesSet(Mongobee.java:123)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1687)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1624)
    ... 19 common frames omitted
```

I do not know if I should configure something else in a file. Mongo is running.

The database I imagine will be created alone, I have already done monolithic projects with Mongo database and I have not had to do anything in the database.

The project is as generated by Jhipster without any change.

In fact the database is created.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error creating bean with name 'mongobee' defined in class path resource](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45208470/error-creating-bean-with-name-mongobee-defined-in-class-path-resource)

Comment: My project has no dependency on guava. :(

Comment: OK, then please show output of `gradlew dependencies`

Comment: The console output in "gradlew dependencies" was very large. I have done a new project and I have chosen maven instead of gradlew and it seems to start well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: You were right for maven, it works but you were wrong about your project not using guava: `gradlew dependencies` showed it is referenced 162 times in 7 different versions. Anyway a bug is open now https://github.com/jhipster/generator-jhipster/issues/6184